# How can a quasi-convex function be concave?

Tags: functions, optimization

Also the reverse, how can a quasi-concave function be convex?

As I understand it all convex functions are also quasiconvex, but not all quasiconvex functions are convex, as quasi-convexity is a generalisation of convexity.

This also applies to concavity so all concave functions are also quasi-concave but not all quasi-concave functions are concave, for the same reason as above.

What I don’t understand then is how exactly these quasi-concave functions that aren’t concave and these quasi-convex functions that aren’t convex can exist.

This is because, for example, a quasi-convex function that isn’t convex must be concave. However, doesn’t this concave + quasi-convex function then violate the fact that all concave functions are also quasi-concave.

Similarly, a quasi-concave function that isn’t concave must be convex but then doesn’t this convex + quasi-concave function violate the fact that all convex functions are also quasi-convex?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=\log x.$ It is concave (so quasiconcave) and also quasiconvex.

For an example of a quasiconvex function that is neither convex nor concave, consider $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{|x|}.$

Comment: Ok thank you. So, for example a quasi-concave function that isn’t concave the only options are:   1) quasi-concave + convex (where therefore it’s also quasi-convex as all convex functions are quasi-convex) or 2) quasi-convex and neither concave/convex. Both of these don’t violate the concave (convex) function has to be quasi-concave  (convex) rules. Are there any other examples of how a quasi-concave (convex) function can not be concave (convex). Thanks.

Comment: Almost exactly correct. A real-valued function on a connected/convex subset of $\Bbb R$ must either be (1) *strictly* concave and therefore quasi-concave but not convex, or (2) *strictly* convex and therefore quasi-convex but not concave, or (3) neither convex nor concave, or (4) both convex and concave and therefore affine ($y=mx+b$). Thus, the only way for a quasi-concave (resp. quasi-convex) function to not be concave (resp. convex) is to be either *strictly* convex (resp. *strictly* concave), or neither convex nor concave.